# Multiple IF conditions meet to return value

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to put in a formula to give me the outcome of 1 if true and 0 if false.

To read as true I need the all 3 of the lookup ups in the IF formula to be met, so if cell F7 (always fixed) on tab one appears in column c on tab 2, and if cell c8 appears on that line in column e tab 2, and finally if there is a value on this line in column M of tab 2 then return the value 1, if not return the value 0.

So if all 3 criteria are met then return 1.

Comment: Welcome. Please include the formula that you tried. Also you should include a brief description of your search/research efforts. References [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like:

```
=if(A1="this1",1,0)*(if(A2="this2",1,0)*if(A3="this3",1,0))
```

[IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)